# String of numbers converted to int and added to a list(Optimization issue)

Tags: python, arrays

I've managed to make the code work but i believe it could be optimized... a lot.

The input is a string of numbers separated with spaces. Something like - `4 2 8 6` or `1 2 3 4 5 6 7`

It has to find which 3 numbers match this `condition a + b == c`. While `'b'` is always on the right side of `'a'` and `for every time the condition is met` print the numbers on the console in the following format - `'a + b == c'`. If there isn't a single match print 'No'.

The only restriction is for `'b'` to be at least 1 index away from `'a'`.

This is what I have come up with.

```
lineOfNums = input('Line of numbers: ') # User input: example - 4 2 6 8
arrNums = lineOfNums.split()
conMet = False # Is the condition met at least once

for a in range(0, len(arrNums)):
    for b in range(a + 1, len(arrNums)):
        for c in range(0, len(arrNums)):
            if int(arrNums[a]) + int(arrNums[b]) == int(arrNums[c]):
                print(f'{arrNums[a]} + {arrNums[b]} == {arrNums[c]}')
                conMet = True

if conMet == False: print('No')
```

Comment: You've outlined a condition in which "a must always be on the right side of be", does this mean it must be directly adjacent or can it be any number on the right of a. And are there any conditions on c? Right now in your current looping construct, you will be checking if a + b == c, where a can be the exact same number as c? I presume, the intention is to find 3 distinct numbers where a + b == c holds true?

Comment: So C doesn't have to be on the right side of B, and there may be numbers between A and B?

Comment: You should break out of the loops when the condition is met.

Comment: Convert all the inputs to `int` when you create `arrNums`, rather than converting them each time through the loop.

Comment: No C doesn't have to be on the right side of B. The only restriction is that the index of B in the array is always at least 1 position away from A. To explain it better i will write it like that:
A - goes through the whole list
B - goes through the whole list while being at least 1 index away from A (B always starts at ' A + 1 '
C - goes through the whole list
I'm sorry for this badly formed question. I will edit it.

Comment: Only reason I ask, is this is framed as an optimization problem. If a and c cannot be the same number (in the list) then you can achieve this with 2 loops instead of 3. Given you know index of b is at index a + 1, you'd only need to loop through the items in the list that do not equal the numbers at a, or a+1 at any given time. You'd be able to achieve this by keeping track of index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, do the integer conversion once when you create `arrNum`, not every time through the loops.

```
arrNum = [int(x) for x in lineOfNums.split()]
```

The outer loop only needs to go to `len(arrNums)-1`, since it needs to leave room for `B` to the right of it.

```
for a in range(0, len(arrNums)-1):
    for b in range(a + 1, len(arrNums)):
        for c in range(0, len(arrNums)):
            if arrNums[a] + arrNums[b] == arrNums[c]:
                print(f'{arrNums[a]} + {arrNums[b]} == {arrNums[c]}')
                conMet = True
```

Comment: It doesn't have to break after it finds a match. I didn't specify that in the question at first but now i edited it. And yes my main concern was how to assign the values from the string to int data type in the array. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with `itertools`, first of course convert to int

`from itertools import combinations`

```
# Convert to int
arr= [int(i) for i in arrNums]

# Get all the combinations
psums = {sum(i): i for i in combinations(arr, 2)}

# Then loop once
for i, v in enumerate(arr):
    if v in psums:
        print(f'{psums[v][0]} + {psums[v][1]} == {v}')
```

The big O for this algorithm is `O(n^2)` on average, which comes from `O(n choose r)`, where `n` is the number of inputs (4 in this example) and `r` is the count of numbers your summing, in this case 2.

Comment: You could also knock it down from O(N^3) to O(N^2 log N) by presorting `arr` and using `bisect.bisect_left` to query for partial sums.

Comment: I was trying to avoid sorting, because I didn't think it would help. Do you know the big O comparison between `combinations` and `bisect.bisect_left`

Comment: I haven't used `itertools` or any other library other than `math`. I'm still a beginer but this really shortens the code and optimizes it. Definitely going to learn about it in the future!

Comment: `itertools` is a builtin python library, very useful for problems like these, does a lot of the heavy lifting

Comment: @Kenan actually, at first I did not notice that you were using set for storing `psums`. Looks like you have average case O(N^2) and an upper bound on the worst case of O(N^3) which might not be sharp. Going the `bisect` route should give the worst case of O(N^2 log N). In hindsight, your approach looks pretty good.

Comment: Average of `O(N^2)` for an initial `O(N^3)` isn't so bad but O(N^2 log N) would be better but I'm not sure if it would be cleaner, maybe you can post your solution?

Comment: Looks like an O(N^2) algorithm is discussed [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-pythagorean-triplet-in-an-unsorted-array/). Going below that is an [open problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3SUM)! I don't think I can contribute much at this point :)